# Jenkins detects SVN changes but doesn't update workspace?

Tags: svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm using Jenkins 1.461 and I have an issue when using SVN polling. My repository URL has the form svn+ssh://***********. I've configured Jenkins to poll for changes every 5 minutes. What happens is that every 5 minutes, changes are detected :

> Started on May 2, 2012 8:26:24 PM Received SCM poll call on  for
>   XXXXXXXXX on May 2, 2012 8:26:25 PM
>   svn+ssh://X.X.X.X/svn/XXXX/XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX/trunk is at revision
>   26,192   (changed from 26,181) Done. Took 2.6 sec Changes found

But, the workspace is not updated after each poll. The last revision of the workspace is still 26181 and not 26192 as expected. I don't understand why. Any idea?

Mickael

Comment: Not that it answers your question, but I would strongly recommend you actually use svn hooks instead. This way your project will only get triggered when there have been commits. No need to be polling all the time -- this can cause you grief, if you have a large number of projects in Jenkins.

Comment: @carlspring Could you give me some links about how it works, please?

Comment: You can have a look at this rather descriptive link https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin . Basically, it's better to set things up so that it doesn't poll for changes all the time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are the clocks on your Jenkins and SVN server in sync? If the clocks are off by even a little, strange things will happen. I do not use SVN much myself, so I do not remember if this was one of the symptoms but it would be good to start by checking the clocks.

Easiest would be to install ntpd on both hosts, configure them to sync against the same source and forget about it. If you do not have an ntp server in your organization, check http://www.pool.ntp.org

Comment: I get a warning before each build indicating the fact that the SVN server isn't synchronized. For now, I've added @HEAD after each SVN URL and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Using @HEAD at the end of SVN URL is actually solving the problem as mentioned by Mickael Marrache in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to resolve the issue.

Click **Enable Auto Refresh** (top right hand corner of the screen)

> 1) Click on my Project
>      2) Click configure
>       3) Under General Tab, scroll down to "Source Code Management"
>       4) Add "@HEAD" behind the Repository URL
>       5) Click "Save"
>       6) Click "Apply"  (Important)
>       7) Click "Build Now" for my project
>
> Click on my Project >> Recent Changes

Now you will see your project gets updated with the most recent commit from your repository.