# Jenkins not building, says "no changes" even though log shows changes

Tags: svn, jenkins

We're running Jenkins 1.577. Most of what we're building/deploying is PHP/MySQL projects, so not so much "building" as "deploying changes" to our staging/testing server. No compiling or anything else happening.

We regularly find that builds are not happening even though it seems they should. For instance, we'll have a job set up to poll SCM every 2 minutes (we use SVN). I click on one of these builds and it says "Revision 32860. No Changes". Immediately below that it says "Started by an SCM change". I click that and I get the polling log, which says:

```
This page captures the polling log that triggered this build.

Started on Jan 1, 2015 12:54:26 AM
Received SCM poll call on  for ZipYourFlyer WP screens on Jan 1, 2015 12:54:28 AM
[URL of build] is at revision 32,879
(changed from 32,860)
Done. Took 4.3 sec
Changes found
```

So...hmm. Polling clearly knows a change occurred, but it isn't building. It's a bit baffling.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it this? Related to system clocks...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418814/jenkins-detects-svn-changes-but-doesnt-update-workspace?rq=1

Comment: Hmm - possible. Checking...

Comment: Ha - that was it, or seems to have been. Builds are deploying on first polling event now, rather than requiring multiple passes to activate. My developers will be very happy - thanks!

Comment: In Subversion, it is possible for the revision to change but all changes since the last checkout to have taken place in different locations so that even when the revision changed, there are still no changes.